# How to get GL_MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE per device

Tags: android

I'd like to reduce images size the minimal amount as possible, so it will fix the GL_MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE so I won't get the texture too large error and so the image won't be too small as well

This might be a stupid question, but trying to use GL_MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE it exists in GL, GL10, GL11, GL20, etc

Which one do I choose?

Answer (score 0):

Those are of which OpenGL ES version the API call is. If you choose OpenGL ES 2.0, you may use `GL20.*`.

OpenGL ES 2.0 is generally chosen these days. From [OpenGL versions and device compatibility](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/opengl#compatibility):

> OpenGL ES 2.0 is supported by most Android devices and is recommended
> for new applications being developed with OpenGL.